# How to download large data from a database table to CSV file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

My requirement is to provide an option to business users to download data.
My oracle stored procedure is returning more than 200 000 data and it can be even more than that also. My stored procedure contains only a select statement and it is returning data fast.

I am fetching data into a DataTable and exporting to CSV file using below code and then flushing to download file.

```
string fileName = "";
DataTable dt = GetData();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
IEnumerable<string> columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                          Select(column => column.ColumnName);
sb.AppendLine(string.Join("|", columnNames));

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString().Replace("12:00:00 AM", "").Replace("00:00:00", ""));
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join("|", fields));
}

Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
fileName = strAppId + "_Mis_" + dtBrsDate.ToShortDateString();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
 "attachment;filename=" + fileName + ".csv");
Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentType = "application/text";
Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

It is working fine if there is a less volume data.
When there is huge volume it is taking more time and application is getting down.

Please suggest me is there any other way to export to data to CSV and download to business users.

Comment: Don't use ASP.NET for starters - all databases provide bulk export facilities. You can export the data to a CSV and eg email it to the user. If you have to do so in your site, *don't* use a DataTable, a StringBuilder, a MemoryStream and *disable* response buffering. Each of these caches *all* the data at once. You'd end up caching all the data 3 times. Use a DbDataReader instead, and write directly to the output stream through eg a StreamWriter instead of a StringBuilder

Comment: The most correct solution is the one by @PanagiotisKanavos as generally creating an entire server to download bulk data is not something optimal. Of course if you want to use asp.net you can workaround that by storing the csv file exported by the sql server ON THE DISK, not memory otherwise the application will crash again, and then reading that file with asp.net.

Comment: I had to google 'Lakhs'.